# svnant: How to checkout specified URLs from a repository?

Tags: svn, ant

Hi all:
i'm using SVNant to checkout a repository, the total repository content is so large and i'm only interest in a few file and directories, the repository structure as below:

```
project
   folder1
   folder2
      largefolder
          largefile1
          largefile2
      folder3
          fileilike1.txt
          fileilike2.txt
   file.txt
   file2.txt
   etc...
```

i'm only interest in the files under project/ folder such as file.txt and file2.txt, and also all files  under folder3. i do not want to checkout largefolder/ because it has extra-large files in it.

how to write the svnant script? i use ignore but seems not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used 'svnant' but I think it should be similar to 'svn'

Here is how you can do this in svn

```
svn co project -N
```

-N forces to check out only the top level files (ie files in project directory only)

then check out individual directory

```
svn up dir1 dir2 dir3
```

When you want to update codebase, do it in two steps

```
svn up -N
svn up
```

Although you can configure to avoid step 1 mentioned above while updating, but the above should work perfectly fine for you.

Comment: thanks for your reply, your solution inspire me try to checkout many times and each time checkout only the folders i need. it works. thanks

Comment: you have to use 'up' command second time to get selected dir. Were you using 'co' or 'checkout' before?

Answer (score 1):

If you're checkout has to be this complicated, perhaps you can rework the project structure.  Are these in fact multiple projects?  I hope you have branches, tags and trunk folders in the layout but chose not to list them for brevity?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of various depths to select what you want in your working directory:

```
#
# First checkout your URL with the immediate files and directories in it
#
$ svn co --depth immediates $URL mydir
A folder1
A folder2
A file.txt
A file2.txt

#
# Let's Update All Folders to infinity except folder2
#
$ shopt -s extglob
$ svn update --set-depth infinity !(folder2)
A folder1/...
A folder3/...
$ cd mydir

#
# Now We'll get immediates under folder2
#
$ cd folder2
$ svn update --set-depth immediates
A largefolder
A folder3

#
# Now we'll exclude largefolder
#
$ svn update --set-depth exclude largefolder
D largefolder

#
# And get everything else in the view
#
$ svn update --set-depth infinity *  # Large Folder Excluded
A [...]
$ cd ..
```

The `--depth` and `--set-depth` switches are fairly new and replace the `-N` switch which stops recursion.

Instead of keeping `largefolder`, you could simply keep `largefolder` around and simply do `svn update <file>` for particular files you may need to update. Once something is in your working directory, the `svn up` will keep it updated. However, you have to be careful because unless you do a `svn up --set-depth`, new files and directories won't be added.